# detect when an html element exits the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a marquee. (tag < marquee >). I would like that when the first element (the span class "span1") stops being seen on the screen, notify me.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/5o4ez17s/

```
    <div id='container_marquee'>
     <marquee id='mymarquee' behavior="scroll" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();">
               <span class='span1'>first marquee text</span>
               <span class='span2'>second marquee text</span>
               <span class='span3'>third marquee text</span>
               <span class='span4'>fourth marquee text</span>
               <span class='span5'>fifth marquee text</span>
     </marquee>
    </div>
```

for example.. :

```
alert("the first span is not visible on screen");
```

I do not want to have a set interval or something, maybe there is a more efficient way to do it. perhaps you could associate a listening event or something.

Comment: Hello @yang! Please check my answer. Hope you will get some idea. Or if you will get some better solution please post your answer.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the `<marquee>` tag is obsolete both in [browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) and by the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/marquee) `jQuery` and/or `CSS` animations should be used instead.

Comment: @Jake this tag has something special, I can add n amount of span in real time without restarting the animation allowing me to have something like an infinite animation. problem that happens to me using jquery. (in this example I do not reflect it.)

Answer (score 0):

You could time it and alert the user when the ticks are finished.

```
    var ticks = 0;
    var timeformarquee = 24; //how long it takes for marquee to hit the edge (seconds)
    var clock = function(){
      ticks++;
      if(ticks === timeformarquee){
       alert("The first span isn't visible on the screen");
      }
    };
    window.setInterval(clock, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

@yavg, I think `setInterval()` is the only way to keep track on marquee visibility according to your requirement :

Try with following script and modified it accordingly :

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        var spanWidth = $(".span1").width();
        /*console.log($(".span1").offset().left);
        console.log($(window).width());*/
        if($(".span1").offset().left >= -spanWidth){
            console.log('Visible');
        }else{
            console.log('Not Visible');
        }
    },1000);
})
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you! what is offset? and why are you doing this  "-spanWidth"?

Comment: For offset please check jQuery official definition http://api.jquery.com/offset/. You will get very good idea. Actually I am first I am getting the span1 width i.e `spanWidth` and then I am comparing it with current position of span1 div from left that why i used `offset`.

Comment: Comparison with span1 current position with negative spanWidth mean span1 is outside the window (not visible). Hope you got the point.